# Serving dynamically cached images from nginx

Tags: nginx

I want to serve thumbnails for images, and these thumbnails are generated on demand, written to disk, then I want to hand them off to nginx to serve.

My root folder for thumbnails is `/var/www/images`. When I get a request for `/thumb/post1/image1.jpg`, I want to process it like this:

1. If the image is present in `/var/www/images/thumb/post1/image1.jpg`, serve it directly.
2. If the image is not there, it needs generating, so pass the request to the API at `@backend`.
3. The API generates the image and writes it to the thumbnail folder, then hands the path to it back to nginx using an `X-Accel-Redirect` header.
4. nginx restarts processing at step 1, which will succeed because the file is now present.
5. If the item the thumb was requested for doesn't exist, the API will return a 404, and nginx should serve a placeholder image located at `/var/www/images/missing.png` instead.

My nginx config looks like this:

```
upstream api {
  server localhost:7440 fail_timeout=0;
}

server {
  root /var/www/www.example.com/public;

  location / {
    try_files $uri @backend;
  }

  location /thumb {
    root /var/www/images;
    try_files $uri @backend /missing.png;
  }

  location @backend {
    root /var/www/api.example.com/public;
    proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
    proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
    proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
    proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;

    proxy_redirect off;
    proxy_pass http://api;

    #For websocket compatibility
    proxy_http_version 1.1;
    proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
    proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
  }
}
```

My thumbnails are kept outside the project folder, so I need a `root` directive in the `/thumb` location to make it look there for the image. The `/` location handles API requests and other static assets and, and the `/thumb` location does the same, but also has the fallback to `missing.png`.

One quirk: for historical reasons my overall `root` folder is not the same as the one used by my `@backend` named location, however, I'm overriding that in both `location` directives, and there is no top-level `try_files`.

However, this doesn't work. Requests for missing images don't get sent to the API, but a fallback for a missing image does! If I remove the fallback, requests *do* get sent to the API, but then the handoff to `x-accel-redirect` fails, even though the file now exists; when the thumb image does exist, nginx doesn't serve it – it just hits the API again.

How should this be configured?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `try_files` statement is incorrect, the named location needs to be the last parameter. Besides, the 404 response is generated by the `location @backend` block, and has nothing to do with the `try_files` statement in the `location /thumb` block.

You should try `proxy_intercept_errors` and `error_page` to handle the 404 response from the backend.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri @backend1;
}
location /thumb {
    root /var/www/images;
    try_files $uri @backend2;
}

proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto $scheme;
proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
proxy_set_header X-NginX-Proxy true;
proxy_redirect off;
proxy_http_version 1.1;
proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";

location @backend1 {
    proxy_pass http://api;
}
location @backend2 {
    proxy_intercept_errors on;
    error_page 404 /missing.png;
    proxy_pass http://api;
}
```

Comment: But the missing image applies only to the `/thumbs` location. The API may return 404s from many other endpoints that should not return images.

Comment: You could use two separate named `locations`

Comment: I don’t get why try_files can’t use a back-end as one of its options to try; isn’t that exactly what it’s for?

Comment: The only function of `try_files` is to test for the existence of local filenames and if they do not exist perform one other function, which may be to branch to a named location, internally rewrite the URI or return a status code. See [the documentation](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

Comment: We managed to make it work partly based on what you said here. One issue we ran into is that images served via these alternative locations failed to have a correct MIME type assigned (as they are when served statically), so we needed to either create a separate `location` for every MIME type, or set the MIME type upstream in the API response.